# How to join multiple tables faster

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm dealing with a old structure and bad design database which is too loose and complicated. Sadly, I have to do it. :(

The old method was used my PHP to query each info from the table. Then I re-coded it with join. But the big problem occured. IT TAKES NEARLY A MINUTE to query these info (sometimes more).

Here's my code:

```
select *, car_db.id as cid, tbl_province.province_name as prov_name,
config_car_color.color_title as clr_title, 
config_car_color.description as clr_desc, 
car_viewer.vwr_id as viewers 
from car_db 
inner join tbl_province on tbl_province.province_code=car_db.prov 
inner join config_car_color on config_car_color.id=car_db.color 
inner join car_viewer on car_viewer.vwr_cid=car_db.id 
where car_db.tid='$_tid'
```

From the latest query of this code it took 3.37 secs. But normally it takes at least 30 secs to run the code.

The question is could you please suggest me what is the best way to process these lines faster.

Comment: can you show your tables schema? maybe I could help you defining indexes on them,

Comment: Could you please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the fields in the db that you are joining on?\

Comment: `$_tid` is [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php), right? If you're using string interpolation to compose queries, you're probably doing it wrong and will get yourself into severe trouble.

Comment: "From the latest query of this code it took 3.37 secs. But it takes at least 30 secs to run the code." Do you mean that the query itself runs in 3.37s, but it takes 30s+ to retrieve the results in PHP?

Comment: What storage engines are you using, what are the indexes, FK's?, primary keys?,... are all the fields you're joining on of the same type even (I've seen UNSIGNED (11)'s joined on VARCHAR(255)'s, which is obviously not a great idea)

Comment: @JW웃 - I would like to post a picture of table schema but I don't know how.

Comment: @fullybaked All the table I joined have indexes.

Comment: Hmm, how about you stop `SELECT *`? We also need to see an `EXPLAIN` and table structures.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - I also need those query from * as well.

Comment: @Wilf: ppl are asking for _crucial_ info: what storage engine are you using, what are the indexes/keys/constraints on the tables... run your query, but write `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ` instead of just `SELECT`. Paste the outcome here. Do the same with this query `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_province`, replacing `tbl_provice` each time, until you've done that with all the tables you're using... post the output here, too. _We need that info to help_

Comment: SELECT * is a likely future maintenance nightmare. Even you want all the columns then specify them all. That said, SELECT * is OK (ish) when you are just debugging a script. Do you have phpmyadmin? If so do an export of the table definitions from there and post them. Also do an explain of the the above query and post the results of that.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - Yes I understand that the schema is needed for this discussion. But I'm running mySQL on phpmyadmin. So the outcome of the command SHOW CREATE TABLE is on a web result. And I can not post it into a comment.

Comment: @Wilf: Edit your question... or use pastebin if needs must

Comment: @Wilf I'm voting to close this question as there is not enough information provided for us to help you.

Comment: Hi This is the table schema : http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/9526/schemacardbk.png

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - Hold on. I've uploaded the picture of table schema.

Comment: @Wilf That's one table. We need to see all the tables involved in this query. Most importantly, we need to see the `EXPLAIN` plan. Put your table definitions in a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - I'm building those tables onto SQLFiddle. Please hold on.

Comment: Straight away it seems you have no index on the tid field that is in your WHERE clause.

Comment: @Kickstart Not to mention it's not normalized.

Answer (score 1):

Create the following indexes:

```
car_db (tid)
tbl_province (province_code) -- might be PK
config_car_color (id) -- might be PK
car_viewer (vwr_cid)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I can see redundancy happening here. Since * would select everything  from all the tables, you're still selecting some of those columns again. Try to select only the columns you need from those tables.